# Does not compile with complete text but, when I compile it separately, it gives me the required output. What should I do?

Tags: errors

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
M&=& \max{\left \{a,b,\frac{a+b}{2},\right}\\
&& a+b,a+b/2\Bigg\}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide the document that causes the error, not the stuff that does compile 'separately'. And don't use `eqnarray*`, that's outdated

Comment: To get the code to compile, you must (a) delete the curly brace (`{`) after `\max` and (b) change `\right}` to `\right.` Moreover, you really shouldn't be using `eqnarray` -- it's badly deprecated! Load the `amsmath` package and use `align` instead. See the posting [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001) for further details.

Comment: It may show correct output when alone, but you get an error message, namely `! Missing delimiter (. inserted).` Never disregard error messages.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the use of package `amsmath`, some options with environment `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \begin{split}
    M = {} & \max\biggl\{ a, b, \frac{a+b}{2},\\
           & a + b, a + \frac{b}{2} \biggr\}
  \end{split}
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
  \begin{split}
    M = \max\biggl\{& a, b, \frac{a+b}{2},\\
                    & a + b, a + \frac{b}{2} \biggr\}
  \end{split}
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
  \begin{split}
    M = {} & \max\{ a, b, (a+b)/2,\\
           & a + b, a + b/2\}
  \end{split}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, you get

```
! Missing delimiter (. inserted).
```

Why do you get “correct” output? Because TeX adds `.` after `\right`, which is missing a delimiter after it; then the `}` balances the `{` after `\max` and all gets in sync. You might fix it by adding the period yourself and removing the useless braces

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
M&=& \max\left \{a,b,\frac{a+b}{2},\right.\\
&& a+b,a+b/2\Bigg\}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

You get

[image]

but this is wrong to begin with.

Firstly, because `eqnarray` is buggy and should not be used for serious work: use `amsmath` environments instead (see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)). Secondly, it's apparent that the braces have different size.

When you split delimiters across lines, both should be given the same size, either automatically or manually. In the case of standard two story fractions the size is `\bigg`; but they should be `\biggl` and `\biggr` (for left and right) in order to get correct horizontal spacing. Hence

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
M&=& \max\biggl\{a,b,\frac{a+b}{2},\\
&& a+b,a+b/2\biggr\}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

might do, but if you look closely, the spaces around the equals sign are awfully big:

[image]

Do you notice the differences with the top picture? Here is what we get with `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` instead:

[image]

Depending on personal preference, you may want to use such smaller size.

Anyway, you should follow Heiko's suggestions as explained in his answer.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for giving context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
M=\max\biggl\{ & a,b,\frac{a+b}{2},\\
              & a+b,a+\frac{b}{2}
      \biggr\}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2-15]

\end{document}
```

[image]